# AWS or Google LoadBalancer for my WebSite Webservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

Can I implement Application LoadBalancing for my web servers using AWS or google cloud. The servers are my own, not part of AWS or google cloud. The flow will be like https: //www.ABC.com --> https: //server1IP. Or https ://server2IP. based on load on the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with AWS Application Load Balancer using IP target type. But it is not possible to use public IP addresses as a target. So such a setup requires a VPN connection between AWS and on premise.

IMHO this might be an option for a migration project for a transition phase but I wouldn't recommend it for production workloads.

Comment: Thanks for the info Henrik.  I have posted another question on stack overflow about this feasibility with Microsoft IIS-ARR.  Please let me know if you have any idea about IIS-ARR.

Comment: Same for GCP LB.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info.